# Holdout results using lm in caret

Tags: r, regression, r-caret, lm

I'm comparing different resampling methods in caret, using only LM. Across multiple datasets and seeds, I'm seeing much better model performance for k-folds, which concerns me that I'm pulling the correct information from the fit object. I wan to know with certainty how to recover holdout model performance when using repeatedcv. How do you recover holdout fold model performance using lm with caret?

In this example below, both boot and LOOCV produce worse model performance using the iris dataset. Given LOOCV uses more data each train, this doesn't make sense to me:

```
fit <- train(Sepal.Width ~ ., method = "lm", data = iris, trControl = trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", number=10, repeats=10))
fit

fit <- train(Sepal.Width ~ ., method = "lm", data = iris, trControl = trainControl(method = "LOOCV"))
fit

fit <- train(Sepal.Width ~ ., method = "lm", data = iris, trControl = trainControl(method = "boot", number=1000))
fit
```

Later, I ran a manual k-folds (non-repeated). This consistently results in worse performance than caret k-folds but similar to LOOCV and boot. I didn't set seeds but you can re-run a few times and R^2 will consistently be lower with the manual method. It is unclear why caret is different.

```
#create folds#
iris <-iris[sample(nrow(iris)),]
folds <- cut(seq(1,nrow(iris)),breaks=10,labels=FALSE)

results <- data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = 0, ncol = 1))  #store results
#Perform 10 fold cross validation
for(i in 1:10){
  testIndexes <- which(folds==i,arr.ind=TRUE)
  testData <- iris[testIndexes, ]
  trainData <- iris[-testIndexes, ]
  print (nrow(trainData))
  print (nrow(testData))
  
  OLS <- lm (Sepal.Width ~ ., data=trainData)
  Predicted <- as.data.frame (predict (OLS, newdata = testData))
  results <- rbind (results, corr.test(cbind (dplyr::select(testData, Sepal.Width), Predicted))$r[2,1])
}
mean (results[,1])^2
```

Comment: There is no guarantee in machine learning sometimes you get a better model just by doing a train/test split

Comment: I re-ran on five datasets and am getting this sort of finding every time. Hence why I worried whether I was incorrectly pulling information out of the "fit" object

Comment: Join us on the tidymodels and stop worrying about that :), caret is very magical, things just work a lot of the time. Also set seeds

Comment: I added more code to compare caret to a manual k folds. Manual k folds results in worse model performance than caret k-fold (but closer to caret LOOCV and boot).

Comment: Create manual folds and run them in caret and manually, do you get equal performance?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean. As shown above, manual k folds does not come very close to caret.

Comment: create folds (train and test indexes) prior to calling train and supply them to train via `index` argument to [train control](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/caret/versions/6.0-86/topics/trainControl). Additionally perform manual calculation as in the question. Are the results the same?

Comment: I'm obtaining opposed results. `method="LOOCV` and  `method="boot` give me better results (however very similar, RMSE ranging between 0.26 and 0.27), which is expected since, as you said, these method uses more training data. Did you take the warning into consideration when running your example? (`In predict.lm(modelFit, newdata) :
  prediction from a rank-deficient fit may be misleading` ) This can produce misleading predictions.